# If element has attribute do something else in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using the qTip plugin to create tooltips for BOTH alt and title tags. The reason for doing this is because in an application I'm working on I can't convert all the alt tags on the images to title tags so have had to use both:

e.g.

```
$('*[title]').qtip({
        content: {
            attr: 'title'
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: false,
            event: 'click mouseleave'
        },
        position: {
            target: "mouse",
            adjust: {
                x: 20,
                y: 10,
                method: "flipinvert flipinvert"
            },
            container: false,
            viewport: true,
            at: "right center",
            my: "left center"
        },
        style: {
            classes: "ui-tooltip-tipsy",
            tip: {
                corner: false
            }
        }
    });

    $('img[alt]').qtip({
        content: {
            attr: 'alt'
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: false,
            event: 'click mouseleave'
        },
        position: {
            target: "mouse",
            adjust: {
                x: 20,
                y: 10,
                method: "flipinvert flipinvert"
            },
            container: false,
            viewport: true,
            at: "right center",
            my: "left center"
        },
        style: {
            classes: "ui-tooltip-tipsy",
            tip: {
                corner: false
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem I have though, is that if I have a link with a title wrapping an image I will get TWO tooltips which is incorrect behaviour.

My idea is to do some logic checking that if the element I am hovering has a title tag or alt tag then only do one or the other and not both.

So for example if `<a href="#" title="Tooltip info"><img src="#" alt="Tooltip info"></a>` then it should use either the alt or title tag in this case.

Can anyone help? Thanks

example:

```
$('a').hover(function() {

if($(this).attr('title')) {
// dont run the alt tag tooltip code
}
});
```

Comment: Use `$('*[title]:not(:has([alt]))')` for the first selector. It will fix the problem I think.

Comment: You should post this as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following selector for the first one

```
$('*[title]:not(:has([alt]))').qtip({.....
```

What it will do is, it will select all elements with `title` attribute which doesn't not have any child element with `alt` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('*[title]:not(:has([alt]))').qtip({
  // code
});
```

will filter among the tag has `title` and exclude those who's child has `alt`.